# closure of the set is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

I have encountered this problem in the book and got stuck for quite a while now. Please help me!

Let $X$ be the set of all $x\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ such that for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $x(n)=0$ whenever $n\geq N$.

How can I show that the closure $\bar{X}$ of $X$ is precisely $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, if $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is endowed with the product topology?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. Define $x_n(k) = \begin{cases} x(k), & k \le n \\ 0, & k > n \end{cases}$. Clearly $x_n \in X$ for all $n$.

We have $x_n \to x$ in the product topology. This follows because $x_n(k) \to x(k)$ for all $k$.

Comment: so this immediately means that the closure of $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, it means that $X$ is dense in $\bar{X}$.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method to copper.hat's, it suffices to show that every nonempty *basic* open set intersects $X$.  For this recall that if $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a *basic* open set, then there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and open sets $U_0 , U_1 , \ldots , U_{N-1} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $$U = U_0 \times U_1 \times \cdots \times U_{N-1} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots.$$ From here it should be easy to see that $U$ intersects $X$.